# Lazy lookup of a dictionary value using a stateless session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, lazy-initialization, stateless-session

In my app, I set up a ternary dictionary mapping so that for a given user, I can retrieve "settings" for each instance of an object that belongs to the user. That is, I have something like:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual IDictionary<Baz, BazSettings> BazSettings { get; set; }

    //...
```

So whenever I have a `Baz` object, I can lookup the current user's baz settings via `currentUser.BazSettings[baz]`.

I would like to be able to use a stateless session to do this, but I get a `LazyInitializationException` with this code:

```
//int bazId;
using (IStatelessSession session = Global.SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
{
    var currentUser = session.Get<User>(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
    var baz = session.Get<Baz>(bazId);
    var bazSettings = currentUser.BazSettings[baz]; // raises `LazyInitializationException`
```

When I use instead an `ISession`, then the problem goes away.

The full NHibernate error message includes the text "no session or session was closed". This makes sense because when using a stateless session, entities are not connected to the session. However, I would think that there is a way to use the stateless session to perform this lookup.

How do I use a stateless session to perform the lookup `currentUser.BazSettings[baz]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stateless sessions do not support lazy loading, exactly because they are **stateless**: they do not track **anything** about the entities retrieved with them.

The only way to make it work is eager loading the collection. But why do you *want* to use stateless sessions, if they clearly do not provide what you need?

Comment: I want to use a stateless session because I only want to read data from the database. What I ended up doing is using an HQL query with the stateless session. It seems to be working well.

Comment: Stateful sessions are not just for writing. Lazy loading and caching are two important features provided by them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ISession instead of IStatelessSession because operations performed using a stateless session do not cascade to associated instances and collections are ignored by a stateless session.

Comment: Cascading has nothing to do with this.